# Array out of Bounds? with string split

Tags: java, arrays

Array out of bounds ? i'm trying to perform the output in the picture:

[image]

Using this INPUT
"JAVA IS A PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE"

This is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Phrase:");
        String s = in.nextLine();

        String[] word=s.split(" ");
        String rts=" ";

        for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
            if(word[i].length()>=rts.length()){
                rts=word[i];
            }
        }

        int thisislength = rts.length();

        for (int a = 0; a < thisislength ;a++ ) {
            for (int b = 0; b < word.length ;b++ ) {
                System.out.print(word[b].charAt(a)+" ");  
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

When the second word reaches its last letter it doesn't continue the for loop, is there any way to continue the loop even if the second word reaches its max length.

Comment: Hint: what do you expect to happen if `word[b].length() == a`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm expecting it to print a blank space if the array goes out of bounds.

Comment: Hey a little tip for your variable names. Names like: 's', 'rts', 'a', 'b' do not indicate what they contain or what they are used for.  If you'd give these variables a better name that describe them self other programmers can read your code much easier.

Comment: i'm sorry @Casper

Comment: You've now changed the code significantly. But you're not checking for the case when `a` is greater than or equal to `word[b].length()`.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, no one has been aware of variable naming since they started programming. We all keep learning :)

Comment: @JonSkeet how do i do that ? isn't that the line i removed ?

Comment: No, the line you removed checked whether `word[b].length()` was *less than* `a`. That doesn't handle the *equal* case. I would strongly suggest stepping through the code in a debugger and thinking about what you want to happen when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` should have been `<=`. Reversing left and right hand sides makes it more readably I think.

```
    for (int a = 0; a < thisislength; a++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d ", a+1);
        for (int b = 0; b < word.length; b++) {
            if (a >= word[b].length()) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            } else {
                System.out.print(word[b].charAt(a));  
            }
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Or instead of the if-else statement:

```
        for (String w : word) {
            System.out.print(a >= w.length() ? ' ' : w.charAt(a));  
        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU, YOU'RE a god

Answer (score 1):

This gives the result you want:

```
for (int a = 0; a < thisislength ;a++ ){
    for (int b = 0; b < word.length ;b++ ){
        if(word[b].length() < a + 1){
            System.out.print("  ");
        }else{
            System.out.print(word[b].charAt(a) + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This line was changed:  
`if(word[b].length() < a + 1)` and not `if(word[b].length() < a)`  
and 2 spaces print in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS SOLUTION HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // GET VALUE FROM THE CONSOLE
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Phrase:");
        String s = in.nextLine();

        // SPLIT STRING TO WORDS
        String[] words = s.split(" ");

        // CREATE A LIST OF CHAR_ARRAY CALLED : matrix
        List<char[]> matrix = new ArrayList<char[]>();

        // REFERENCE THE LARGEST WORD IN WORDS ARRAY EX : PROGRAMMING IS THE LARGEST 
        int max = 0;

        // FILL OUR LIST OF ARRAY OF CHARS
        for (int b = 0; b < words.length ;b++ ) {
            char[] chars =  words[b].toCharArray();
            max = (chars.length >= max)? chars.length :  max ;
            matrix.add( chars );
        }

        // PRINT OUR CHAR
        for (int a = 0; a < max ;a++ ) {

            for (int b = 0; b < words.length ;b++ ) {

                if(a < matrix.get(b).length) {
                    System.out.print(matrix.get(b)[a]);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println("");

        }

    }
}
```